# Navigating inside jar file to see where the output is lost?

Tags: java, file, package, output

I am new to Java. I have an `Example.java` file with following four lines:

```java
/* 1  */ import com.sunsetsoft.xa.Optimizer; 
/* …… */ 
/* 34 */ model = new Optimizer(25000);
/* …… */ 
/* 87 */ System.out.println("First Hello World");
/* 88 */ model.solve(); 
/* 89 */ System.out.println("Second Hello World");
```

The package `com.sunsetsoft.xa.Optimizer` is in a `jar` file. When I run `Example.java`, the output is:

```
First Hello World
```

and line `89` is not executed. Why? `model.solve()` prints some output at a file called `a.log` but this output doesn't have any `Second Hello World`. How can I understand which part of the `com.sunsetsoft.xa.Optimizer` package is either terminating the execution of `Example.java` before line `89`, or redirecting `Second Hello World` to some unknown location?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `model.solve()` and run in debug mode. Of course you should have the source code of the jar.

Comment: what's the type of the `model` ?

Comment: @SeanBright I didn't have the source code for `model.solve()`, so I decompiled the `jar` files which include `model.solve()`. Is this ok? For C++ is use `GBD`. Is `GBD` the common debugger in Java world?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi the type of `model` is `Optimizer` and in line 30 of my code I have `Optimizer model = null;`.  The `Optimizer` class is defined in `import com.sunsetsoft.xa.Optimizer` package.